# How to create column name pattern matching for data classification in Azure Purview?

Tags: regex, azure, azure-purview

All I'm trying to do is simply classify a field as "Date of Birth" if the column name contains any of the following:

- DateofBirth
- BirthDate
- DOB
- YMDBIRTH

I'm not a huge RegEx user, but I usually can figure it out with a few googles. I have tried all of the following in a **Custom Data Classification Rule**:

`DateofBirth|BirthDate|DOB|YMDBIRTH`

`/DateofBirth/|/BirthDate/|/DOB/|/YMDBIRTH/`

`.*DateOfBirth.*|.*BirthDate.*|.*DOB.*|.*YMDBIRTH.*`

`/.*DateOfBirth.*|.*BirthDate.*|.*DOB.*|.*YMDBIRTH.*/i`

None of these have appeared to work... I'm beginning to think it has something to do with my scans... is there some sort of Lag?

I even just used YMDBIRTH on the Classification rule and it still didn't classify the column after the scan completed.

According to this Microsoft Document I think the very first method I have documented here should have worked "**DateofBirth|BirthDate|DOB|YMDBIRTH**"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/create-a-custom-classification-and-classification-rule

### According to the document it says:

Optionally, if the data usually is in a column that they know the name of, such as Employee_ID or EmployeeID, they can add a column pattern regular expression to make the scan even more accurate. An example regex is **Employee_ID|EmployeeID**

So using this, I would think should work:
[Classification Rule Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IofFd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unaware of this, but in the scan rule sets, if you create a new **custom rule** that you believe replaces a **System Rule** and you uncheck the system rule. It appears that the Scan rule will not apply your custom rule...

For me I had Date of Birth system rule unchecked, after checking it (along with my custom rule) it worked and properly classified the column

See Screenshot: [Selected Classification Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL6Jr.png)

Also, my first method of classification **DateofBirth|BirthDate|DOB|YMDBIRTH** was correct, and worked just fine after this.

Answer (score 1):

due to naming conventions in our databases we had to get a bit more creative as columns had names like fs_address or address1, FP_address2, address_line3. This is what I used to match address like column names for address related fields

`/\w*address\w*|\w*street\w*|\w*city\*w|\w*country\w*|\w*postal\w*|\w*prov\w*/i`

\w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

* matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times
This allows the pattern to match PR_ADDRESS_line1 to /\w*address\w*

and the /i on the end makes it case insensitive

I hope this helps